# How to add a movie to my watchlist in IMDb, in the movie page?

Tags: imdb

This seems to be a trivia question, but I can't find a button to add a movie into my watch list, in **that movie page**. The only button I can find is in the recommendation box:

[image: image description]

I know that I can add a movie through my watch list page, but that's not what I'm looking for:

[image: image description]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is the new site of IMDB then the "Add to watchlist" icon is just in front of the movie title. See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Next to the movie's title, there should be an icon which looks a bit like a ribbon with a plus sign in it. If you mouseover, it should tell you what it does.

Click that to add it to your watchlist.

[image: "Click to add to watchlist"]

If it's already on your watchlist, it'll have a green checkmark. Click to remove it.

[image: "Click to remove from watchlist"]